# GAP/HAPcocyclic: How to work with CcGroups

Tags: gap

This is probably not a conceptual question- but I would appreciate any suggestions.

I am trying to construct central extensions of certain infinite groups (for example, a crystallographic space group in two dimensions) by $\mathbb Z_n$. Using the CcGroup function in the HAPcocyclic package of GAP, I am formally able to do this, but the extension is given as a "cocyclic group", which I cannot convert into any of the standard group forms that can be used for further computations in GAP. This extension doesn't have a standard description in GAP and therefore using functions such as IdGroup didn't work for me.

I would like to be able to find the cohomology of the central extension that I constructed. Is there a way I can accomplish this (with the CcGroup function or by any other functions in GAP/HAP)?

Comment: I'm not sure what the appropriate place for this question is, but I think it's probably not here, since your question seems to be software-related rather than mathematical.

Comment: You should contact Graham Ellis and ask him as HAP was developed by him at Galway.

Comment: [This package](http://hamilton.nuigalway.ie/CHA/projects/projectsHAPcocyclicindex.html) is dated 2008 and has never been redistributed with GAP. The file `tst/ccgroup.tst` has examples with `IdGroup` - are those reproducible? If not, it might be that GAP evolved since 2008 and HAPcocyclic needs to be updated. Or maybe there is a newer version, incorporated into another part of the HAP project? I hope the authors will be able to clarify this.